# How can I repeat this cycle of slideshow so that it plays again when it reaches the last element

Tags: javascript

Basically, I know that a variable like count has to be used to store the original number of elements in an array, but the part where it should be attached to the loop is unclear. Any help would mean a lot.
Thanks!

```js
        let slider = document.getElementById('slider');
        const imagesArray = [
       'https://images.pexels.com/photos/572897/pexels-photo-572897.jpeg? auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
       'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2832039/pexels-photo-2832039.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
       'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2574643/pexels-photo-2574643.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940'
       ]

       let count = 0; //I know that we need this, but can't think of attaching it to the array somehow.
       imagesArray.forEach((image, i) => {
       window.setTimeout(() => {
         slider.style.backgroundImage = `url(${image})`;
       }, 1000 * i);
       });
```

```css
#slider{
  width:auto;
  height:300px;
  margin:16px;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating `images.length` timeouts in a loop, define a function that shows the "current" image and sets a timeout to show the next image.

Then it's easy to modify that to "wrap around" to the beginning:

```
function showNext(i) {
  if (i === imagesArray.length) {
    i = 0; // wrap around
  }
  slider.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imagesArray[i]})`;
  
  setTimeout(() => showNext(i+1), 1000)
}

showNext(0); // start
```

---

Your loop approach doesn't work if you want to restart at the beginning since it explicitly says "for every element in the array do this one time".

Comment: Well, that's clean! I came up with a pretty similar approach earlier but could not finish it well. Although, now I see where I went wrong.

Thanks again.